# Why doesn't my discord bot respond to any command that I give in the chat

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, bots

The problem that I am facing is that my discord bot does not respond or read the messages that I am writing in the chat.
The out put of the code down bellow is the users name and nothing else.

```py
import discord
import random

TOKEN ='example'

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as{0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = (message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')
 
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.channel.name == 'example':
        if user_message.lower() == 'Hello':
            await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}')
    elif user_message.lower() == 'bye':
        await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}')
    elif user_message.lower() == '!random':
        response = f'This is your number: {random.randrange(1000000)}'
        await message.channel.send(response)
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: You are missing `'` after `bye`

Comment: Also a lower case command can never equal `"Hello"` since it contains a upper case letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Intents.default()` doesn't include the `Message Content` intent, which is now required. Without the intent, `message.content` will be empty.

More information in the docs:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#privileged-intents

Answer (score 1):

The .lower() method only searches for lower case letters in a string, hence the name, so typing "Hello" into the chat will not trigger the command, as "Hello" has a capital "H". To fix your code you can either:

Change your code to

```py
if user_message.lower() == 'hello':
   await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}')
```

Notice you can still keep the capital H for hello in

```
await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}')
```

Or, you could compare 2 values like this:

```py
string = 'Hello'
if user_message == string:
   #the rest of your code goes here
```

Your full code should be:

```py
import discord
import random

TOKEN ='exemple'

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as{0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = (message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')
 
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.channel.name == 'example':
        string = 'Hello'
        if user_message.casefold() == string:
            await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}')
        elif user_message.lower() == 'bye':
            await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}')
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == '!random':
            response = f'This is your number: {random.randrange(1000000)}'
            await message.channel.send(response)
            return 
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bot can't read the content of the messages sent in a guild because it is missing the message_content intent.

You gave your bot only the default intents, which doesn't include the message_content one.

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

Here is how you fix it:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

In case your bot isn't still able to read the content of the guild messages, you need also to turn on the message content intent in the Discord Developer Portal:

Select your app
Go to the "Bot" tab
Turn the "message content intent" on
Now your bot should be able to read the content of the messages sent in guilds.