# Discord Bot (PY) Not responding to commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot in python. I have done this before but things seems to have changed please help.

`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from colorama import Fore


# Create a new bot instance with intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True  # Enable member-related events


# Create a new bot instance
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix='$', 
    intents=intents
)

# Event that runs when the bot is ready
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(Fore.CYAN, f'Logged in as: ', Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX, f'{bot.user.name}', Fore.RESET)
    print(Fore.CYAN, f'Bot ID: ', Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX, f'{bot.user.id}', Fore.RESET)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message) -> None:
    if message.author == bot.user or message.author.bot:
        return message
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong I am online.')
    print(Fore.WHITE, "COMMANDS WORKING", Fore.RESET)
```

When i first wrote the code i didnt have the on_message function. I added it and made sure to add bot.process_commands. Still didnt work. I checked the bots permissions. Also working.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to enable the `message_content` privileged intent.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True  # Enable member-related events
intents.message_content = True

# Create a new bot instance
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix='$', 
    intents=intents
)
```

Also remember to enable it in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Comment: Please see [answer]. Flag such questions as duplicates and post a shortened version as a comment (not as an answer). Please don't answer duplicates that don't need reasonable amount of case-specific modification of code.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your answer to include links to the Discord Developer Portal, related docs about intents and the API docs. (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html, https://discord.com/developers/applications, and https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bots or https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder find me a duplicate I'll delete my answer and close the question. Also after 700+ answers I think I know how to do it. 

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder You provided many irrelevant links here. The link to the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and the one to the [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message_content#discord.Intents.message_content) are the only ones needed here, as the OP knows the basic structure of how to build a bot.

Comment: @Dominik, I sent the whole set of commonly used basic discord.py links.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński, there're many dupes; shouldn't be hard to get one. Some which I picked blindly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025292/why-doesnt-my-discord-bot-respond-to-any-command-that-i-give-in-the-chat, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72694788/message-content-intent-is-not-enabled-prefix-commands-may-not-work-as-expected, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74158933/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-message-in-discord-py and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74071838/cant-receive-the-message-content-with-discord-bot. I'm not asking you to delete your answer,LOL; avoid hereafter

Comment: Tysm this worked